# How to fix the page footer at the bottom margin in MS' Reporting Services?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

please kindly advise how to fix the page footer at the bottom margin in Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services? The default situation is that the footer will be displayed at the next line of the last row of the Body section.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sigh... I found that the preview of the report DOES NOT have the same result from actual printing. While printing out the report, the footer locates at the bottom margin indeed